# Resolving MongoDB DBRef array using Mongo Native Query and working on the resolved documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB collection is made up of 2 main collections :

1) Maps

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("542489232436657966204394"),
"fileName" : "importFile1.json",
"territories" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "territories",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5424892224366579662042e9")
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "territories",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5424892224366579662042ea")
    }
]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542489262436657966204398"),
    "fileName" : "importFile2.json",
    "territories" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "territories",
            "$id" : ObjectId("542489232436657966204395")
        }
    ],
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2012-08-22T09:06:40.000Z")
}
```

2) Territories, which are referenced in "Map" objects :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5424892224366579662042e9"),
    "name" : "Afghanistan",
    "area" : 653958
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5424892224366579662042ea"),
    "name" : "Angola",
    "area" : 1252651
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542489232436657966204395"),
    "name" : "Unknown",
    "area" : 0
}
```

My objective is to list every map with their cumulative area and number of territories. I am trying the following query :

```
db.maps.aggregate(
    {'$unwind':'$territories'},
    {'$group':{
        '_id':'$fileName',
        'numberOf': {'$sum': '$territories.name'}, 
        'locatedArea':{'$sum':'$territories.area'}
        }
    })
```

However the results show 0 for each of these values :

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "importFile2.json",
            "numberOf" : 0,
            "locatedArea" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "importFile1.json",
            "numberOf" : 0,
            "locatedArea" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I probably did something wrong when trying to access to the member variables of Territory (name and area), but I couldn't find an example of such a case in the Mongo doc. area is stored as an integer, and name as a string.

Comment: Joins aren't supported in MongoDB.  You cannot reference `$territories.name` in your aggregation query on the `maps` collection.  It has to be done client side.

Comment: One option is to rethink how you store the data.  If you can store the documents itself in the `territories` array, instead of storing references, this would be simple query, as just the `maps` collection would have all data required.  Generally speaking, in MongoDB, you'd want to store the data in the way application would access it, thus eliminating the need for joins.

Comment: @bperel Although Joins should be avoided, they are not inevitable. The above schema cannot be a embedded one since it would lead to redundancy. And one suggestion would be to use manual references rather than DBRefs just for the fact that it makes querying a bit easier.

Comment: Use map-reduce instead of aggregate.

Comment: `Map-reduce` cannot be used to solve this problem, since it would need to access the database to resolve the database references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I probably did something wrong when trying to access to the member variables of Territory (name and area), but I couldn't find an example
>   of such a case in the Mongo doc. area is stored as an integer, and
>   name as a string.*

Yes indeed, the field `"territories"` has an array of [database references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref) and `not the actual documents`. `DBRefs` are objects that `contain information with which we can locate the actual documents`.

In the above example, you can clearly see this, fire the below mongo query:

```
db.maps.find({"_id":ObjectId("542489232436657966204394")}).forEach(function(do
c){print(doc.territories[0]);})
```

it will print the DBRef object rather than the document itself:

```
o/p: DBRef("territories", ObjectId("5424892224366579662042e9"))
```

so, `'$sum': '$territories.name'`,`'$sum': '$territories.area'` would show you '0' since there are no fields such as `name` or `area`.

So you need to resolve this reference to a document before doing something like `$territories.name`

To achieve what you want, you can make use of the `map()` function, since aggregation nor Map-reduce support sub queries, and you already have a self-contained `map` document, with references to its `territories`.

Steps to achieve:

```
a) get each map
b) resolve the `DBRef`.
c) calculate the total area, and the number of territories.
d) make and return the desired structure.
```

Mongo shell script:

```
db.maps.find().map(function(doc) {
    var territory_refs = doc.territories.map(function(terr_ref) {
        refName = terr_ref.$ref;
        return terr_ref.$id;
    });
    var areaSum = 0;
    db.refName.find({
        "_id" : {
            $in : territory_refs
        }
    }).forEach(function(i) {
        areaSum += i.area;
    });
    return {
        "id" : doc.fileName,
        "noOfTerritories" : territory_refs.length,
        "areaSum" : areaSum
    };
})
```

o/p:

```
[
        {
                "id" : "importFile1.json",
                "noOfTerritories" : 2,
                "areaSum" : 1906609
        },
        {
                "id" : "importFile2.json",
                "noOfTerritories" : 1,
                "areaSum" : 0
        }
]
```

`Map-Reduce` functions should not be and cannot be used to resolve `DBRefs` in the server side.
See what the documentation has to say:

> The map function should not access the database for any reason.
>
> The map function should be pure, or have no impact outside of the
>   function (i.e. side effects.)
>
> The reduce function should not access the database, even to perform
>   read operations. The reduce function should not affect the outside
>   system.

Moreover, a `reduce` function even if used(which can never work anyway) will never be called for your problem, since a group w.r.t `"fileName"` or `"ObjectId"` would always have only one document, in your dataset.

> MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a
>   single value

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer ! Is your code adaptable to a map-reduce process like S.D. suggests ? I don't know the impacts in terms of performance but it looks like map-reduce is made for this kind of select-and-transform process.

Comment: @bperel:see my updated answer as to why DBRefs cannot be resolved using Map-Reduce.